# the word “abandoned” following a noun

Tags: word-usage

I was trying to write a sentence but not sure if I’m using the word correctly.

Can I say “with feelings abandoned” when I’m trying to explain that we abandoned these feelings. I try not to use “abandoned feelings”
I was hoping “with feelings abandoned” works.

Thank you :)

Comment: It is hard to answer this without the full sentence. Give us the sentence you have written.

Comment: *With feelings abandoned* is grammatical, but it's also poetic and would sound strange as part of a regular sentence.

Comment: I want to say “we go on with life with feeling abandoned” is it correct?